# What's the strange format data in python?

Tags: python, ajax, django

When I use the ajax post to my api, I get the bellow information, I did not saw this data type, who can explain this:

```
{
    u'params[memory_cpu_address][3][cpu]': u'1\u6838', 
    u'params[bandwidth][bandwidth]': u'1M', 
    u'params[security_setting][example_name]': u'lasd01', 
    u'params[memory_cpu_address][2][model]': u'\u6807\u51c6\u578b\u4e00', 
    u'params[server_count][server_length]': u'1\u53f0', 
    u'params[operating_system][system_edition]': u'Windows2003',       
    u'params[memory_cpu_address][0][address]': u'\u6df1\u5733',    
    u'params[security_setting][user_name]': u'root', 
    u'params[storage][data_disk][disk_length]': u'0', 
    u'params[storage][system_disk][type]': u'SSD', 
    u'params[security_setting][user_password]': u'lasd01',     
    u'params[memory_cpu_address][4][memory]': u'1G', 
    u'params[total_prices][prices]': u'430', 
    u'params[memory_cpu_address][1][usable-area]': u'\u6df1\u5733\u4e00\u533a', 
    u'params[operating_system][system_name]': u'Windows', 
    u'params[storage][data_disk][type]': u'SSD',
    u'params[time_buying][deta_time]': u'1\u6708', 
    u'params[storage][system_disk][disk_length]': u'40'
}
```

My ajax code is :

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'/app_api/buy_server/',
    data:{'params':buy_data},   # buy_data is a dictionary in js
    success:success_func,
})
```

My views.py code is :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    post_querydict = request.POST

    post = post_querydict.dict()

    print (post)
```

How can I get the normal dictionary format? because this type data, I can not get the data like this `post.get("params")` method.

Comment: you have to `jsonify` the data whether it be on the client side or server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your data as JSON as deserialize it in Python.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/app_api/buy_server/',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({'params':buy_data}),
    success: success_func,
})
```

...

```
post_data = json.loads(request.body)
print(post_data)
```